# react native : Best navigator/router component to use with redux

Tags: react-native, redux

i'm starting a new react native app, with redux and drawer based navigation, i'm looking for the best navigator/router component to choose , i would appreciate recommendation based on experience please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 3.15.2017
based on the comment from Thomas you can use https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation

Based on the comments from here you should use NavigationExpermiental:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6184

Here's a nice example to get you started:
https://github.com/thebakeryio/react-native-complex-nav

Comment: So for now (2017) this is: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation